# How do I get the number of Facebook-like for each picture?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have created a website (to practise my PHP+MYSQL skills)

The URL is http://rot47.net/picture-gallery/

The page allows you to upload any single photo quickly without registration.
and I 've put a FB-like button on the page where the single photo is shown, such as
http://rot47.net/share-picture/x

So, how could I make use of the statistics here? I want to create another single page that lists the popular photos 'liked-by-facebook' (sorted desc by FB-like numbers).

Is this possible? and how to do this efficiently? (for example, I have a million pictures, but I just want to know the top 100 pictures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt to solve this problem.
http://helloacm.com/picture-explorer-sort-pictures-by-facebook-likes/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link, that will return you number of likes and shares in JSON format:

> https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.example.com/

Comment: thanks. and do you have any suggestions regards to the efficiency? what I meant (as stated in the question) to get the top 100 photos out of a million.

Comment: Don't know about that. Probably not good idea to get data like this for 1M photos ;) Try looking at [graph api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), maybe there is some kind of batch request that supports this.